# creating contact.asp

Tags: asp.net, html

I am trying to link my HTML5 website to a contact form so it can send email to a specific address.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sunset Events</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen">    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://info.template-help.com/files/ie6_warning/ie6_script_other.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body id="page5">
<div class="main">
<!--==============================header=================================-->
    <header>
        <h1><a href="index.html">Wedding Planner</a></h1>
    </header>
<!--==============================content================================-->
    <section id="content">
        <article class="col-1">
            <figure><img src="images/page5-img1.jpg" alt=""></figure>
            <img class="title" src="images/page5-title.png" alt="">
        </article>

        <article class="col-3">
            <div class="padding">               


                          <font style="color:white; font-size:large;" >CONTACT INFO<br />
                        <br>
                        <dl>
                            <dt >Sunset events<br /><br>BEIRUT- LEBANON</dt><br>
                            <dd><span >Telephone / FAX : <font style="font-size:11px; color:#ccc;">+961 1 484556</font></dd><br><br>
                            <dd><span >MOBILE :<font style="font-size:11px; color:#ccc;"> +961 3 301459</font></dd><br><br>
                            <dd><span >E-mail : <font style="font-size:11px; color:#ccc;">info@sunsetevents.net</font></dd><br><br>
                            <dd><span >Facebook : <a class="linkfb" href="http://www.facebook.com/SunsetWeddingsAndEventss" target="_blank" >SunsetWeddingsAndEventss</a></dd>
                        </dl>



            </div>
        </article>


               <article class="col-2">


                    <div class="padding" style="margin-left:-40px;">

                          <font style="color:white; font-size:large;" >FEEDBACK <img src="images/contact.png" 
                          style="margin-top:-70px; margin-left:200px;">
                          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/close.png" style="float:right; margin-top:-60px; margin-right:-50px;" ></a><br />

                        <form id="form-main" action="contact.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <fieldset>
                                <table>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <label><span class="input"><input name="name" value="Full Name" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Full Name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Full Name' ) this.value=''" /></span></label></td>
                                <td >
                                <label style="margin-left:10px;"><span class="input"><input name="name" value="E-mail" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='E-mail'" onFocus="if(this.value =='E-mail' ) this.value=''" /></span></label></td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <label><span class="input"><input name="name" value="Tel" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Tel'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Tel' ) this.value=''" /></span></label>
                                </td>
                                <tD>
                                <label style="margin-left:10px;"><span class="input"><input name="name" value="Fax" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Fax'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Fax' ) this.value=''" /></span></label>
                                </tD></tr></table>
                                <table>
                                <tr>
                                <tD>
                                <label ><span class="input"><input name="name" value="Activity" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Activity'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Activity' ) this.value=''" /></span></label>
                                </tD>
                                <td>

                                <select name="Country" class="dropdown"> 
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option> 
                                <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
                                <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
                                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
                                <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option> 
                                <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option> 
                                <option value="Angola">Angola</option> 
                                <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option> 
                                <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option> 
                                <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option> 
                                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option> 
                                <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option> 
                                <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option> 
                                <option value="Australia">Australia</option> 
                                <option value="Austria">Austria</option> 
                                <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option> 
                                <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option> 
                                <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option> 
                                <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option> 
                                <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option> 
                                <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option> 
                                <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option> 
                                <option value="Belize">Belize</option> 
                                <option value="Benin">Benin</option> 
                                <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option> 
                                <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option> 
                                <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option> 
                                <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option> 
                                <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option> 
                                <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option> 
                                <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option> 
                                <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option> 
                                <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option> 
                                <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option> 
                                <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option> 
                                <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option> 
                                <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option> 
                                <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option> 
                                <option value="Canada">Canada</option> 
                                <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option> 
                                <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Chad">Chad</option> 
                                <option value="Chile">Chile</option> 
                                <option value="China">China</option> 
                                <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option> 
                                <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option> 
                                <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option> 
                                <option value="Congo">Congo</option> 
                                <option value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option> 
                                <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option> 
                                <option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option> 
                                <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option> 
                                <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option> 
                                <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option> 
                                <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option> 
                                <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option> 
                                <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option> 
                                <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option> 
                                <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option> 
                                <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option> 
                                <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option> 
                                <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option> 
                                <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option> 
                                <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option> 
                                <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option> 
                                <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option> 
                                <option value="Finland">Finland</option> 
                                <option value="France">France</option> 
                                <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option> 
                                <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option> 
                                <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option> 
                                <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option> 
                                <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option> 
                                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option> 
                                <option value="Germany">Germany</option> 
                                <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option> 
                                <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option> 
                                <option value="Greece">Greece</option> 
                                <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option> 
                                <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option> 
                                <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option> 
                                <option value="Guam">Guam</option> 
                                <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option> 
                                <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option> 
                                <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option> 
                                <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option> 
                                <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option> 
                                <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option> 
                                <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option> 
                                <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option> 
                                <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option> 
                                <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option> 
                                <option value="India">India</option> 
                                <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option> 
                                <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option> 
                                <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option> 
                                <option value="Israel">Israel</option> 
                                <option value="Italy">Italy</option> 
                                <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option> 
                                <option value="Japan">Japan</option> 
                                <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option> 
                                <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option> 
                                <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option> 
                                <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option> 
                                <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option> 
                                <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option> 
                                <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option> 
                                <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option> 
                                <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option> 
                                <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option> 
                                <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option> 
                                <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option> 
                                <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option> 
                                <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option> 
                                <option value="Macao">Macao</option> 
                                <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option> 
                                <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option> 
                                <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option> 
                                <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option> 
                                <option value="Mali">Mali</option> 
                                <option value="Malta">Malta</option> 
                                <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option> 
                                <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option> 
                                <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option> 
                                <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option> 
                                <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option> 
                                <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option> 
                                <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option> 
                                <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option> 
                                <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option> 
                                <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option> 
                                <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option> 
                                <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option> 
                                <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option> 
                                <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option> 
                                <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option> 
                                <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option> 
                                <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option> 
                                <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option> 
                                <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option> 
                                <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option> 
                                <option value="Niger">Niger</option> 
                                <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option> 
                                <option value="Niue">Niue</option> 
                                <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option> 
                                <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Norway">Norway</option> 
                                <option value="Oman">Oman</option> 
                                <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option> 
                                <option value="Palau">Palau</option> 
                                <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option> 
                                <option value="Panama">Panama</option> 
                                <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option> 
                                <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option> 
                                <option value="Peru">Peru</option> 
                                <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option> 
                                <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option> 
                                <option value="Poland">Poland</option> 
                                <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option> 
                                <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option> 
                                <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option> 
                                <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option> 
                                <option value="Romania">Romania</option> 
                                <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option> 
                                <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option> 
                                <option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option> 
                                <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option> 
                                <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option> 
                                <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option> 
                                <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option> 
                                <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option> 
                                <option value="Serbia and Montenegro">Serbia and Montenegro</option> 
                                <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option> 
                                <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option> 
                                <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option> 
                                <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option> 
                                <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option> 
                                <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option> 
                                <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option> 
                                <option value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Spain">Spain</option> 
                                <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option> 
                                <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option> 
                                <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option> 
                                <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option> 
                                <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option> 
                                <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option> 
                                <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option> 
                                <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option> 
                                <option value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan, Province of China</option> 
                                <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option> 
                                <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option> 
                                <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option> 
                                <option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option> 
                                <option value="Togo">Togo</option> 
                                <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option> 
                                <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option> 
                                <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option> 
                                <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option> 
                                <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option> 
                                <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option> 
                                <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option> 
                                <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option> 
                                <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option> 
                                <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option> 
                                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                                <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                                <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option> 
                                <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option> 
                                <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option> 
                                <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option> 
                                <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option> 
                                <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option> 
                                <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option> 
                                <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option> 
                                <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option> 
                                <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option> 
                                <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option> 
                                <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option> 
                                <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                                </select>

                                </td>
                                </tr></table>

                               <div class="area"><textarea onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Message:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Message:' ) this.value=''">Message:</textarea></div>
                                <div class="buttons">                                        
                                    <a class="link-1" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('form-main').reset()">Clear</a>
                                    <a class="link-1" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('form-main').submit()">Send</a>
                                </div>  
                            </fieldset>

                        </form>

                    </div>

        </article>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </section>
<!--==============================footer=================================-->
    <footer>
        <span  style="margin-left:50px;">Sunset Events &copy; 2013 | </span>
        Follow us:
        <span> 
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/SunsetWeddingsAndEventss" target="_blank" data="Facebook"><img class="fb" src="images/fb.png" ></a> 
        </span>
        <span style="margin-right:30px;">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/@sunsetWE" target="_blank" data="Twitter"><img class="fb" src="images/twitte.png" ></a> 
        </span>
<br>
        <span >By <a href="http://designerds.net/" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/designerdslogo.png" style="margin-top:2px;"></a></span>
        <!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

AND THIS IS THE CONTACT.ASP

```
 ‘—-Settings———–
subj = “Contact form from your site” – (here you can change heading message which you will receive in the letter from guest)
mail_from = “admin@tsie.loc” – (here you need to put your website mail address )
mail_to = “andy@template-help.com” – (here you need to put your own email address)
smtp_server = “localhost” – (here you need to put SMTP server name of your server )
smtp_port = 25 – (here you need to put SMTP port of your server)
```

THIS IS THE ERROR MSG

> [HttpException (0x80004005): The HTTP verb POST used to access path
>   '/demo/contact.asp' is not allowed.]
>   System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +2523961
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155